# R doesn't find the variables in a data frame from tigerstats

Tags: r

I dowloaded the dataframe Titanic from the library Tigerstats. I want to use the barchartGC and chisqtestGC functions with the variables Sex and Survived, but i get the same error everytime:

```
barchartGC(~Sex+ Survived, data = Titanic,
       type = "percent", 
       main = "Survival Rate by Sex")
```

and I get this error:

```
Error in get(varName, inherits = T) : object 'Sex' not found
```

The same happens with the chi test:

```
chisqtestGC(~ Sex + Survived, data = Titanic, graph = T)
```

Output:

```
Error in get(varName, inherits = T) : object 'Sex' not found
```

I've run the code from the beginning several times and I don't understand why this happens.

I've been using rstudio since September and I don't have so much experience, I'm sorry in advance

Comment: There does not appear to be titanic dataset that comes up with the tigerstats package. You might be confusing it with the dataset that comes with base R. In which case, you first need to convert the data set to a data frame using `as.data.frame(Titanic)`.

Comment: Thank you, I tried using as.data.frame() but I still get the same error

Comment: This works for me: `barchartGC(~Sex + Survived,data=as.data.frame(Titanic))`